# Storing data in datebase using jQuery Ajax Post mathod via RESTful Resource Controller in Laravel 5.2

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I'm trying to store some data in a form using Jquery Ajax (using the POST method). I'm using RESTful resources controller to handle the store request. When using a form with POST method it is possible to use the route as `/student/store`.But how can we route to the store method in the controller in this method. Simplified code is as follows. Help needed.

```
("#btnSave").click(function(){
    console.log("btnSave");
    $.post("/student",
    {        
        name: $("#studentname").val(),
        age: $("#studentage").val(),
        marks: $("#marks").val()

    },function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With resource routes,

```
Route::resource('student', 'StudentController');
```

The `POST` request is routed to the `store()` method by default. You can see the url by doing the following in console:

```
php artisan route:list | grep student
```

If you are manually adding the form fields into the ajax request, you are forgetting the CSRF token. Add the following inside your form if the hidden `_token` field is missing:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

And update your ajax request to reflect the new `_token` field:

```
$.post("/student",
{        
    name: $("#studentname").val(),
    age: $("#studentage").val(),
    marks: $("#marks").val(),
    '_token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
}
```